# How to keep your code clean with denormalized data?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, denormalization

I'm going to ask this question in two parts: first the general question, and than the question for my specific use case.

## The general question:

I'm building a podcast app, where, hopefully, we'll have users. Users have subscripitons, settings, ... , which I'd like to store on the User object, but subscriptions and settings don't belong in the same module in my code.

How do you structure your code so that all the relevant data about a user is stored together, but the code that defines and deals with specific properties can be separated?

## My specific use case

I'm building the back end on Google App Engine. My user class looks something like this:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    ...
```

Now I could just add another property for subscriptions, settings etc, but these definitions don't really belong in the users module. I've tried defining a `SubscriptionsHolder` and `SettingsHolder` class using `ndb.PolyModel`, but with multiple inheritance, only queries on the last superclass in the User definition supports querying.

I could just make the `settings` and other module query the User model directly, but this results in a circular dependency, where the User the `users` module depends on `settings` for subclassing, and `settings` depends on `users` for querying. I know I can resolve the circular dependency by moving the import statement around, but that just seems like a hack to me.

Comment: What about to use StructuredProperty or LocalStructuredProperty inside of User to store Settings?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using to store settings, but I didn't want that property to be defined inside the users module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach was to treat `User` and `Settings` data as separate but related collections.  Instead of subclassing or using `PolyModel` I simply introduced a way to imply a 1:1 relation between those data sets.

One way is to add a `KeyProperty` to `Settings` that links back to `User`.  Another way is to create each `Settings` entity with the same id/name that is used by the related `User` entity.  This second way allows a direct `Settings.get_by_id()` call once you have the `User` key.

Comment: This is handy, but you're incurring overhead, because you need 2 `model.get()` operations to get both the user and their settings. I'd like to store them on the same model, so I can do a single `User.get`, and get everything associated with that user.

Comment: If the data must be retrieved in a single request, then add the fields to the `User` collection.  But with `ndb`, once you've retrieved a `User` entity it remains in cache so the second request is much faster.  Requesting a `Settings` entity by key is also faster than using a query, so the overhead really isn't that bad.